# How to make this kind of aggregation in Mongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, mongoengine

I have MongoDB 4.x with collection, which have documents like this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbzJx.jpg)

how to make agregation, that return only bot-field, where _id is X?
I've tried to use $project:

`{
    _id: 0,
    bot: {$filter: {
        input: '$clusters.bots',
        as: 'bot',
        cond: {$eq: ['$$bot._id', 'X']}
      }}
    }`

Comment: So what code in Python have you tried so far?

Comment: @connectyourcharger i'll try thousands of variants, e.g.
    from core import modules

    bot = modules.Owner.objects.aggregate({
        '$project': {
            'bot': {
                '$eq': [
                    'clusters.bots.id',
                    1
                ]
            }
        }
    })

but I understand why it isn't valid :(